# How to append a div to another element in document? UPDATED

Tags: javascript, ruby, appendchild

**UPDATED - Check answer**

I have a track-card with an overflow:hidden property.

In each track-card, I have a (+) symbol,

when i click it, a pop up appears within the track-card.

I am using JS to hide/unhide the popup as shown below:

```
const pressAddToPlaylist = () => {
    const cards = document.querySelectorAll(".track-card");
    console.log(cards);
    cards.forEach((card) => {
        card.querySelector(".addtoplaylist").addEventListener("click", function () {
            card.querySelector(".pop-up").className = card.querySelector(".pop-up").className.replace(/(?:^|\s)hidden-popup(?!\S)/g, '');
        });
    });
}
```

Here is the popup

```
<% @track.each do |track| %>
// some code
 <div class="pop-up hidden-popup" id="popup">
   <h1>Choose Playlist</h1>
 <div class="playlist-form">
     <%= simple_form_for @playlist_track, url: playlist_tracks_path, method: :post do |f| %>
     <%= f.association :playlist, :collection => Playlist.all, label_method: :playlist_title %>
     <%= f.input :track_id, as: :hidden, input_html: { value: track.id } %>
     <%= f.submit "Create" %> 
     <% end %>
 </div>
<% end %>
 </div>
```

track-card css

```
.track-card {
    width: 250px;
    height: 480px;
    backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    overflow:hidden;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
```

PROBLEM:
I want the popup to appear outside of the track-card. Problem is, track-card is the parent div with the property overflow:hidden. The popup also contains a form which depends on the @track loop that collects track.id to include in the form on submission.

I have tried a couple ways to override overflow:hidden with css but no luck. I am now trying some JS to append popup to the body of the document. I think by appending the popup to an element outside of the track-card, I will still be able to collect track.id while rendering the popup without the parent overflow:hidden influencing the popup.

I was thinking something like this

```
document.querySelectorAll('trackpopup').appendChild(document.getElementById('popup')

// trackpopup is the destination that popup  must be appended to.
```

P.S. I have tried using absolute on child and relative on parent but no luck

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to append my popup to a div at the beginning of the doc that does not have any overflow or grid styling.

```
document.querySelector('#trackpopup').appendChild(document.querySelector('.pop-up'));
```

this works for me so I am marking this question answered.